# Log In with view change

Tags: ios, if-statement, view, authentication

I created a Log In Screen for my iPhone App which should change from the Log In View to the Main View if the entered password is correct but I don't know how to change views in an if statement... 
here is what if done so far (is'nt much, I know)

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MainViewViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController



- (IBAction)enterPassword
{
    NSString *passwordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"12345"];

    if ([passwordField.text isEqualToString:passwordString]) {

    }

    else {
        UIAlertView *correctPassword = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Falsches Passwort" message:@"Dieses Passwort ist falsch! Geben Sie bitte das korrekte Passwort ein!"   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Zurück" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [correctPassword show];
    }
}

- (IBAction)switchView:(id)sender {
    MainViewViewController *main = [[MainViewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:main animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

This is the whole ViewController.m file and I want to put the switchview Action into the if statement. How do i change Views in an if statement.

Could you please help me, I would appreciate that 
Thanks Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, assuming your `switchView` method is working properly, just call it inside your if statement.

```
- (IBAction)enterPassword
{
    NSString *passwordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"12345"];

    if ([passwordField.text isEqualToString:passwordString]) {
        [self switchView:nil];
    }
    else 
    {
        UIAlertView *correctPassword = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Falsches Passwort" message:@"Dieses Passwort ist falsch! Geben Sie bitte das korrekte Passwort ein!"   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Zurück" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [correctPassword show];
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help! You can upvote and accept my answer, in order to remove it from the unanswered section :)